# Is it correct to `source $f` when `$f` is a shell script with an `eval` in it?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I use `fasd`, an autocompletion utility. It has an initialization step that asks you to put `eval "$(fasd --init auto)"` into your `.bashrc`. Running this produces the following:

```
eval "$(fasd --init posix-alias bash-hook bash-ccomp bash-ccomp-install)"
```

I moved `eval "$(fasd ..."` out of my `.bashrc` and into a different file to keep my .bashrc unmodified, so that I instead just have:

In `.bashrc`:

```
source config/fasd.sh
```

In `config/fasd.sh`:

```
eval "$(fasd --init auto)"
```

When I do this, `fasd` no longer seems to function correctly -- namely the autocompletion no longer seems to be initialized correctly. Have I misunderstood how `source` works, or is this a bug in `fasd`?

Comment: Did you try to use a full path. E.g. something like `source ~/config/fasd.sh` or `/home/userdir/config/fasd.sh`

Comment: The file's getting sourced correctly, in that `source` definitely hits the right path. (For example if I add `echo "test!"` as the first line of `config/fasd.sh`, it is shown.)

Comment: Does it work properly when you move the `eval` command back into your bashrc?

Comment: BTW, you really should use the full path in the source command: `source ~/config/fasd.sh`.

Comment: Yes, moving `eval "$(fasd --init auto)"` back to `.bashrc` causes it to work again.

Comment: You could try defining a variable or function in the sourced script (`~/config/fasd.sh`), restart the shell, and see if the var/func exists. I'm not sure if that will prove anything, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: You could file a bug on [the project on GitHub](https://github.com/clvv/fasd/issues). I just checked and didn't find anything similar to this issue.